# Fastest way to convert 29th February into 1st March in R?

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have a vector of dates ("YYYY-MM-DD") in R, which contain some 29th February. For simplicity of my analysis, I want to convert these dates into 1st March. I am doing this using a for loop, but I wondered if there is a faster way as I will apply it to tens of thousands of dates.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(lubridate)
dates0 <-  as.POSIXlt(as.Date(c("1945-04-09 UTC", "1957-06-10 UTC", "1924-02-28 UTC",
             "1921-06-22 UTC","1926-05-16 UTC", "1920-02-29 UTC")))

dates0[6]

for(i in 1:6){
  if(day(dates0[i])==29 & month(dates0[i])==2) day(dates0[i]) <- 1; month(dates0[i]) <- 3
}

dates0[6]
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to store the dates as `Date` instead of `POSIXlt` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more onerous method than user2974951 offered, but more easily generalised if the date change is more than a single day step:

```
tochange <- day(dates0) == 29 & month(dates0) == 2
month(dates0[tochange]) <- 3
day(dates0[tochange]) <- 1
```

In terms of fastest:

```
dates1 <- rep(dates0, times = 1000)

OP <- \(x) {
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    if(day(x[i])==29 & month(x[i])==2) day(x[i]) <- 1; month(x[i]) <- 3
  }
}

setBoth <- \(x) {
  tochange <- day(x) == 29 & month(x) == 2
  month(x[tochange]) <- 3
  day(x[tochange]) <- 1
}

incrementDay <- \(x) {
  tmp=month(x)==2 & day(x)==29
  x[tmp]=x[tmp]+days(1)
}

microbenchmark(
  OP           =  OP(dates1),
  setBoth      =  setBoth(dates1),
  incrementDay =  incrementDay(dates1)
)

Unit: milliseconds
         expr    min      lq     mean  median     uq      max neval cld
           OP 1.1611 1.38955 1.839490 1.67015 1.8911   8.3134   100   a
      setBoth 1.2863 1.44650 3.456468 1.63335 1.7768 158.1885   100   a
 incrementDay 1.1924 1.41305 1.765843 1.53635 1.7587   7.8440   100   a
```

There doesn't seem to be a lot in it, my way likely slowest.

Comment: Interesting to see that the for loop was not as bad as I thought!

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
tmp=month(dates0)==2 & day(dates0)==29
dates0[tmp]=dates0[tmp]+days(1)
```

Comment: I think this is what I am going to use, based on the speed analysis provided by @Paul Stafford Allen.

Answer (score 2):

In case there is no need to use `POSIXlt` it would gain much speed when using `Date`, where, when found the 29 Feb., simply 1 needs to be added and this works in *base*.

```
i <- which(format(dates1, "%m%d") == "0229")
`[<-`(dates1, i, value = dates1[i] + 1) }
```

Data

```
dates1 <- as.Date(c("1945-04-09 UTC", "1957-06-10 UTC", "1924-02-28 UTC",
                    "1921-06-22 UTC","1926-05-16 UTC", "1920-02-29 UTC"))
dates0 <- as.POSIXlt(dates1)
```

---

Benchmark

```
incrementDay <- \(x) {   #@user2974951
  tmp <- month(x)==2 & day(x)==29
  x[tmp] <- x[tmp]+days(1)
  x }

idLub <- \(dates1) {
    i <- which(month(dates1)==2 & day(dates1)==29)
    `[<-`(dates1, i, value = dates1[i] + 1) }

idBase <- \(dates1) {
    i <- which(format(dates1, "%m%d") == "0229")
    `[<-`(dates1, i, value = dates1[i] + 1) }

bench::mark(incrementDay =  incrementDay(dates1),
            idLub =  idLub(dates1),
            idBase =  idBase(dates1) )
```

Result

```
 expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
  <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
1 increment… 441.3µs 454.7µs     2161.      328B     14.4  1048     7      485ms
2 idLub       46.2µs  48.8µs    20060.    21.8KB     21.0  9531    10      475ms
3 idBase      28.8µs  30.9µs    31793.        0B     22.3  9993     7      314ms
```

Using `Date` instead of `POSIXlt` decreases the time in this case by a factor of 10.